# Error when defining a dust.js filter

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I'm using the full, Linked In version 1.2.0 of dust.js and am trying to define a filter for use when rendering a JSON view with a dust template. When I include this line in the page script:

```
_.extend(dust.filters, {foo: function(value){ return 'foo'; }});
```

it results in this error in Chrome's debugger:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined**

If I add the filter definition to where the other filters are in the dust .js file, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file that defines the new filter is being run before underscore ( _ ) is being run. Thus, underscore is undefined.

Comment: OK, having never written code that extends the functionality of a js object, and replicating filter-creation code I found that uses "_.extend", I don't know how to fix this. This line of code is inside a jquery $(document).ready(function() {}) call.

Comment: _.extend is a part of the Underscore.js. You can get it here: http://underscorejs.org/